# How to add a TextField to Alert in SwiftUI?

Tags: alert, textfield, swiftui

Anyone an idea how to create an Alert in SwiftUI that contains a TextField?

[image: sample_image]

Comment: Here you go https://gist.github.com/gurjitdhiman/38ee1be49e5767cdf8833e4c68094e02

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As the `Alert` view provided by `SwiftUI` doesn't do the job you will need indeed to use `UIAlertController` from `UIKit`. Ideally we want a `TextFieldAlert` view that we can presented in the same way we would present the `Alert` provided by `SwiftUI`:

```
struct MyView: View {

  @Binding var alertIsPresented: Bool
  @Binding var text: String? // this is updated as the user types in the text field

  var body: some View {
    Text("My Demo View")
      .textFieldAlert(isPresented: $alertIsPresented) { () -> TextFieldAlert in
        TextFieldAlert(title: "Alert Title", message: "Alert Message", text: self.$text)
    }
  }
}
```

We can achieve this writing a couple of classes and adding a modifier in a `View` extension.

1) `TextFieldAlertViewController` creates a `UIAlertController` (with a text field of course) and presents it when it appears on screen. User changes to the text field are reflected into a `Binding<String>` that is passed during initializazion.

```
class TextFieldAlertViewController: UIViewController {

  /// Presents a UIAlertController (alert style) with a UITextField and a `Done` button
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - title: to be used as title of the UIAlertController
  ///   - message: to be used as optional message of the UIAlertController
  ///   - text: binding for the text typed into the UITextField
  ///   - isPresented: binding to be set to false when the alert is dismissed (`Done` button tapped)
  init(title: String, message: String?, text: Binding<String?>, isPresented: Binding<Bool>?) {
    self.alertTitle = title
    self.message = message
    self._text = text
    self.isPresented = isPresented
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  // MARK: - Dependencies
  private let alertTitle: String
  private let message: String?
  @Binding private var text: String?
  private var isPresented: Binding<Bool>?

  // MARK: - Private Properties
  private var subscription: AnyCancellable?

  // MARK: - Lifecycle
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    presentAlertController()
  }

  private func presentAlertController() {
    guard subscription == nil else { return } // present only once

    let vc = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    // add a textField and create a subscription to update the `text` binding
    vc.addTextField { [weak self] textField in
      guard let self = self else { return }
      self.subscription = NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification, object: textField)
        .map { ($0.object as? UITextField)?.text }
        .assign(to: \.text, on: self)
    }

    // create a `Done` action that updates the `isPresented` binding when tapped
    // this is just for Demo only but we should really inject
    // an array of buttons (with their title, style and tap handler)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default) { [weak self] _ in
      self?.isPresented?.wrappedValue = false
    }
    vc.addAction(action)
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

2) `TextFieldAlert` wraps `TextFieldAlertViewController` using the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` protocol so that it can be used within SwiftUI.

```
struct TextFieldAlert {

  // MARK: Properties
  let title: String
  let message: String?
  @Binding var text: String?
  var isPresented: Binding<Bool>? = nil

  // MARK: Modifiers
  func dismissable(_ isPresented: Binding<Bool>) -> TextFieldAlert {
    TextFieldAlert(title: title, message: message, text: $text, isPresented: isPresented)
  }
}

extension TextFieldAlert: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

  typealias UIViewControllerType = TextFieldAlertViewController

  func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<TextFieldAlert>) -> UIViewControllerType {
    TextFieldAlertViewController(title: title, message: message, text: $text, isPresented: isPresented)
  }

  func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType,
                              context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<TextFieldAlert>) {
    // no update needed
  }
}
```

3) `TextFieldWrapper` is a simple `ZStack` with a `TextFieldAlert` on the back (only if `isPresented` is true) and a presenting view on the front. The presenting view is the only one visibile.

```
struct TextFieldWrapper<PresentingView: View>: View {

  @Binding var isPresented: Bool
  let presentingView: PresentingView
  let content: () -> TextFieldAlert

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      if (isPresented) { content().dismissable($isPresented) }
      presentingView
    }
  }  
}
```

4) The `textFieldAlert` modifier allows us to smoothly wrap any SwiftUI view in a `TextFieldWrapper` and obtain the desired behaviour.

```
extension View {
  func textFieldAlert(isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
                      content: @escaping () -> TextFieldAlert) -> some View {
    TextFieldWrapper(isPresented: isPresented,
                     presentingView: self,
                     content: content)
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to `import Combine` to make make `AnyCancellable` visible

Comment: It will pop current page

Comment: Anyone used this with the .alert(item: Item, alert: (Item) -> Alert) API?

Comment: I am handling this alert under a button. Somehow I can capture the value that was entered in the modal. How can I make sure get the value from it after tapping the button from the modal?

Answer (score 35):

`Alert` is quite limited at the moment, but you can roll your own solution in pure SwiftUI.

Here's a simple implementation of a custom alert with a text field.

```swift
struct TextFieldAlert<Presenting>: View where Presenting: View {

    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    @Binding var text: String
    let presenting: Presenting
    let title: String

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { (deviceSize: GeometryProxy) in
            ZStack {
                self.presenting
                    .disabled(isShowing)
                VStack {
                    Text(self.title)
                    TextField(self.title, text: self.$text)
                    Divider()
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.isShowing.toggle()
                            }
                        }) {
                            Text("Dismiss")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.white)
                .frame(
                    width: deviceSize.size.width*0.7,
                    height: deviceSize.size.height*0.7
                )
                .shadow(radius: 1)
                .opacity(self.isShowing ? 1 : 0)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And a `View` extension to use it:

```swift
extension View {

    func textFieldAlert(isShowing: Binding<Bool>,
                        text: Binding<String>,
                        title: String) -> some View {
        TextFieldAlert(isShowing: isShowing,
                       text: text,
                       presenting: self,
                       title: title)
    }

}
```

---

**Demo**:

[image]

```swift
struct ContentView : View {

    @State private var isShowingAlert = false
    @State private var alertInput = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.isShowingAlert.toggle()
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Show alert")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("A List"), displayMode: .large)
        }
        .textFieldAlert(isShowing: $isShowingAlert, text: $alertInput, title: "Alert!")
    }
}
```

Comment: this gives me Abort 6 error. result not found
Cross-reference to module 'SwiftUI'
... View
... in an extension in module ... opaque return type of

Comment: @MobileMon please double check your code - I just tested this on macoS 10.15 b2 / Xcode 11 b2 and it compiles fine without issues. Tested on both sim and device.

Comment: This compiles for me but the TextField won't allow editing.  It's like it's disabled or something.

Comment: I had to change `TextField(self.$text)` to `TextField(self.title, text: self.$text)` to make it compile but I cannot edit the text either.

Comment: @simibac  You can find the fix here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59493767/swiftui-textfield-acts-disabled-in-vstack-inside-zstack-simulating-an-alert-wit

Comment: to fix editing, I changed "let presenting: () -> Presenting "  " self.presenting()
                    .blur(radius: self.isShowing ? 2 : 0)
                    .disabled(self.isShowing)" and TextFieldAlert(isShowing: isShowing,
                       text: text,
                       presenting: { self },

Comment: Works except for the extra ".textFieldAlert" function. That function ends up replacing the NavigationView since the method returns a totally different view.

Comment: This works... but for some reason it kills all the animation when I put my List in and out of edit mode. Very weird.

Answer (score 27):

**iOS 16+**

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var presentAlert = false
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Alert") {
            presentAlert = true            
        }
        .alert("Login", isPresented: $presentAlert, actions: {
            TextField("Username", text: $username)

            SecureField("Password", text: $password)

            
            Button("Login", action: {})
            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel, action: {})
        }, message: {
            Text("Please enter your username and password.")
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can simply use `UIAlertController` directly. No need to roll your own alert dialog UI:

```swift
private func alert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField() { textField in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter some text"
    }
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in })
    showAlert(alert: alert)
}

func showAlert(alert: UIAlertController) {
    if let controller = topMostViewController() {
        controller.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}

private func keyWindow() -> UIWindow? {
    return UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
    .filter {$0.activationState == .foregroundActive}
    .compactMap {$0 as? UIWindowScene}
    .first?.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
}

private func topMostViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    guard let rootController = keyWindow()?.rootViewController else {
        return nil
    }
    return topMostViewController(for: rootController)
}

private func topMostViewController(for controller: UIViewController) -> UIViewController {
    if let presentedController = controller.presentedViewController {
        return topMostViewController(for: presentedController)
    } else if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
        guard let topController = navigationController.topViewController else {
            return navigationController
        }
        return topMostViewController(for: topController)
    } else if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
        guard let topController = tabController.selectedViewController else {
            return tabController
        }
        return topMostViewController(for: topController)
    }
    return controller
}
```

Most of this code is just boilerplate to find the ViewController that should present the alert.
Call `alert()` e.g. from the `action` of a button:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { alert() }) { Text("click me") }
     }
}
```

Please beware though that there seems to be a bug in beta 5 and onward that can sometimes cause the emulator to freeze once a text field is shown: [Xcode 11 beta 5: UI freezes when adding textFields into UIAlertController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57509557/xcode-11-beta-5-ui-freezes-when-adding-textfields-into-uialertcontroller/57843362#57843362)

Comment: This works fine in both iOS and MacOs. Also in MacOS this standard alert is very unstable, but solid in iOS: `.alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) { Alert(title: Text("title"), message: Text("message"), primaryButton: .default(Text("Ok")), secondaryButton: .cancel (Text("Cancel")))}` why is the question?

Comment: How do you access the values in the textField?

Comment: This is a decent answer, however this breaks my layout, once the dialog is shown, until the views state is changed again. It causes the spacing on the left and right side of the view to become larger...

Comment: This answer was brilliant and saved me a lot of time

Comment: @Genki `alert.textFields!.first!.text!`. Reference: https://medium.com/swift-india/uialertcontroller-in-swift-22f3c5b1dd68

Answer (score 12):

I found modals and alerts in SwiftUI to be lacking several features. For instance, there doesn't seem to be a way of presenting a modal with FormSheet style.

When I need to present a complex alert (such as one with textfields), I create a pure SwiftUI view with all the content of the alert, and then present it as a FormSheet using a **UIHostController**.

If you do not have a UIViewController around to call present(), you can always use the root view controller.

With this approach you get some nice features, such as the standard alert animation both going in, and out. You can also drag the alert down to dismiss it.

The alert view also moves up when the keyboard appears.

***This works nicely on iPad. On iPhone, FormSheet is full screen so you may need to tweak the code to find a solution. I think this will give you a good starting point.***

[image]

It is something like this:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var showAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                let alertHC = UIHostingController(rootView: MyAlert())

                alertHC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 200)
                alertHC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.formSheet

                UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController?.present(alertHC, animated: true)

            }) {
                Text("Show Alert")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyAlert: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("Enter Input").font(.headline).padding()

            TextField($text, placeholder: Text("Type text here")).textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder).padding()
            Divider()
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})
                }) {

                    Text("Done")
                }
                Spacer()

                Divider()

                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})
                }) {
                    Text("Cancel")
                }
                Spacer()
            }.padding(0)


            }.background(Color(white: 0.9))
    }
}
```

If you find yourself using this a lot, the button row may be encapsulated in a separate view for easy reuse.

Comment: Any lead for iPhone workarounds? BTW iPad will also show it fullscreen when sharing screen with another app.

Comment: **Swift5 update** Update the TextField line to this ->.  TextField("Type text here", text: $text).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle()).padding()

Comment: By the way this will not work in the preview for the iPhone.  You will have to build it in the simulator and it looks quite different for iPhone.  the above only looks like this in the iPad simulator.

Comment: kontiki This appears to not work under Xcode 12.2. Create a new project and past the code in and the preferredContentSize value appears to get ignored.

Answer (score 11):

Simple native solution for iOS

```
extension View {

    public func textFieldAlert(
        isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
        title: String,
        text: String = "",
        placeholder: String = "",
        action: @escaping (String?) -> Void
    ) -> some View {
        self.modifier(TextFieldAlertModifier(isPresented: isPresented, title: title, text: text, placeholder: placeholder, action: action))
    }
    
}
```

```
public struct TextFieldAlertModifier: ViewModifier {

    @State private var alertController: UIAlertController?

    @Binding var isPresented: Bool

    let title: String
    let text: String
    let placeholder: String
    let action: (String?) -> Void

    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.onChange(of: isPresented) { isPresented in
            if isPresented, alertController == nil {
                let alertController = makeAlertController()
                self.alertController = alertController
                guard let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else {
                    return
                }
                scene.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true)
            } else if !isPresented, let alertController = alertController {
                alertController.dismiss(animated: true)
                self.alertController = nil
            }
        }
    }

    private func makeAlertController() -> UIAlertController {
        let controller = UIAlertController(title: title, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        controller.addTextField {
            $0.placeholder = self.placeholder
            $0.text = self.text
        }
        controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in
            self.action(nil)
            shutdown()
        })
        controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in
            self.action(controller.textFields?.first?.text)
            shutdown()
        })
        return controller
    }

    private func shutdown() {
        isPresented = false
        alertController = nil
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var isRenameAlertPresented = false
    @State private var title = "Old title"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Rename title") {
                isRenameAlertPresented = true
            }

            Text(title)
        }
        .textFieldAlert(
            isPresented: $isRenameAlertPresented,
            title: "Rename",
            text: "Title",
            placeholder: "",
            action: { newText in
                title = newText ?? ""
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this working and it does what I needed. However the example usage was fairly vague. I spent a while trying to troubleshoot why errors were popping up. You could show the example with a code block instead of `rename`. Also, the line `UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true)` uses a deprecated approach. It should be replaced with `(UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as! UIWindowScene).windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true)`. I thought another error happened too that was easily fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I updated the example and removed deprecated API.

Comment: How can I set the input of TextField as Autocapitalization ? thanks

Comment: It's very simple) Just add the code `$0.autocapitalizationType = .words` after `$0.text = self.text`

Answer (score 6):

Although not exactly the same, if all you're looking for is a native, modal-like view with an edit box, you could use a [popover](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/07/24/alerts-actionsheets-modals-and-popovers-in-swiftui/). It works out of the box (minus a [sizing bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58179317/swiftui-sizing-a-popover-to-fit)) without needing to traverse the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 5):

As already was mentioned `Alert` is provide not many functionality and so almost useless in any non-standard cases when using in SwiftUI.

I ended up with a bit extensive solution - `View` that may behave as alert with high customisation level.

1. Create `ViewModel` for popUp:

   ```
   struct UniAlertViewModel {

    let backgroundColor: Color = Color.gray.opacity(0.4)
    let contentBackgroundColor: Color = Color.white.opacity(0.8)
    let contentPadding: CGFloat = 16
    let contentCornerRadius: CGFloat = 12
   }
   ```
2. we also need to configure buttons, for this purpose let's add one more type:

   ```
   struct UniAlertButton {

    enum Variant {

        case destructive
        case regular
    }

    let content: AnyView
    let action: () -> Void
    let type: Variant

    var isDestructive: Bool {
        type == .destructive
    }

    static func destructive<Content: View>(
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) -> UniAlertButton {
        UniAlertButton(
            content: content,
            action: { /* close */ },
            type: .destructive)
    }

    static func regular<Content: View>(
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content,
        action: @escaping () -> Void
    ) -> UniAlertButton {
        UniAlertButton(
            content: content,
            action: action,
            type: .regular)
    }

    private init<Content: View>(
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content,
        action: @escaping () -> Void,
        type: Variant
    ) {
        self.content = AnyView(content())
        self.type = type
        self.action = action
    }
   }
   ```
3. add View that can become our customizable popUp:

   ```
   struct UniAlert<Presenter, Content>: View where Presenter: View, Content: View {

    @Binding private (set) var isShowing: Bool

    let displayContent: Content
    let buttons: [UniAlertButton]
    let presentationView: Presenter
    let viewModel: UniAlertViewModel

    private var requireHorizontalPositioning: Bool {
        let maxButtonPositionedHorizontally = 2
        return buttons.count > maxButtonPositionedHorizontally
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                backgroundColor()

                VStack {
                    Spacer()

                    ZStack {
                        presentationView.disabled(isShowing)
                        let expectedWidth = geometry.size.width * 0.7

                        VStack {
                            displayContent
                            buttonsPad(expectedWidth)
                        }
                        .padding(viewModel.contentPadding)
                        .background(viewModel.contentBackgroundColor)
                        .cornerRadius(viewModel.contentCornerRadius)
                        .shadow(radius: 1)
                        .opacity(self.isShowing ? 1 : 0)
                        .frame(
                            minWidth: expectedWidth,
                            maxWidth: expectedWidth
                        )
                    }

                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func backgroundColor() -> some View {
        viewModel.backgroundColor
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .opacity(self.isShowing ? 1 : 0)
    }

    private func buttonsPad(_ expectedWidth: CGFloat) -> some View {
        VStack {
            if requireHorizontalPositioning {
                verticalButtonPad()
            } else {
                Divider().padding([.leading, .trailing], -viewModel.contentPadding)
                horizontalButtonsPadFor(expectedWidth)
            }
        }
    }

    private func verticalButtonPad() -> some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<buttons.count) {
                Divider().padding([.leading, .trailing], -viewModel.contentPadding)
                let current = buttons[$0]

                Button(action: {
                    if !current.isDestructive {
                        current.action()
                    }

                    withAnimation {
                        self.isShowing.toggle()
                    }
                }, label: {
                    current.content.frame(height: 35)
                })
            }
        }
    }

    private func horizontalButtonsPadFor(_ expectedWidth: CGFloat) -> some View {
        HStack {
            let sidesOffset = viewModel.contentPadding * 2
            let maxHorizontalWidth = requireHorizontalPositioning ?
                expectedWidth - sidesOffset :
                expectedWidth / 2 - sidesOffset

            Spacer()

            if !requireHorizontalPositioning {
                ForEach(0..<buttons.count) {
                    if $0 != 0 {
                        Divider().frame(height: 44)
                    }
                    let current = buttons[$0]

                    Button(action: {
                        if !current.isDestructive {
                            current.action()
                        }

                        withAnimation {
                            self.isShowing.toggle()
                        }
                    }, label: {
                        current.content
                    })
                    .frame(maxWidth: maxHorizontalWidth, minHeight: 44)
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
   }
   ```
4. to simplify usage let's add extension to `View`:

   ```
   extension View {

    func assemblyAlert<Content>(
        isShowing: Binding<Bool>,
        viewModel: UniAlertViewModel,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content,
        actions: [UniAlertButton]
    ) -> some View where Content: View {
        UniAlert(
            isShowing: isShowing,
            displayContent: content(),
            buttons: actions,
            presentationView: self,
            viewModel: viewModel)
    }
   }
   ```

And usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isShowingAlert: Bool = false
    @State private var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    isShowingAlert.toggle()
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Show alert")
            })
        }
        .assemblyAlert(isShowing: $isShowingAlert,
                       viewModel: UniAlertViewModel(),
                       content: {
                        Text("title")
                        Image(systemName: "phone")
                            .scaleEffect(3)
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        TextField("enter text here", text: $text)
                        Text("description")
                       }, actions: buttons)
        }
   }
 }
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: I really liked this answer and have added it to my SwiftUI helpers. I have a few minor changes: (i) !requireHorizontalPositioning check in horizontalButtonsPadFor(..) not needed, (ii) I wanted the horizontal divider between two buttons to not have top nor bottom spaces like standard alerts... so VStack(spacing: 0) in buttonsPad(..) AND when !requireHorizontalPositioning in the main UniAlert body do not have "bottom" viewModel.contentPadding for the VStack with the content and button pad views AND removed the last Spacer below the ZStack.

Comment: thanks for comment, glad that this answer helps u. I will definitely check and update the code a bit later. Meanwhile u may also faced with case when u want to present this alert over full contenxt of your view. how to do this - u can find small article here - https://khorbushko.github.io/article/2020/11/24/present-view-over-full-context.html

Answer (score 3):

This is an example based on the SwiftUI `Sheet` class that displays a dialog with a prompt, a text field, and the classic OK and Dismiss button

[image]

[image]

First lets make our `Dialog` class, which will pop when user want to edit a value:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Dialog: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    /// Edited value, passed from outside
    @Binding var value: String?

    /// Prompt message
    var prompt: String = ""
    
    /// The value currently edited
    @State var fieldValue: String
    
    /// Init the Dialog view
    /// Passed @binding value is duplicated to @state value while editing
    init(prompt: String, value: Binding<String?>) {
        _value = value
        self.prompt = prompt
        _fieldValue = State<String>(initialValue: value.wrappedValue ?? "")
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(prompt).padding()
            TextField("", text: $fieldValue)
            .frame(width: 200, alignment: .center)
            HStack {
            Button("OK") {
                self.value = fieldValue
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
            Button("Dismiss") {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
            }.padding()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct Dialog_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        var name = "John Doe"
        Dialog(prompt: "Name", value: Binding<String?>.init(get: { name }, set: {name = $0 ?? ""}))
    }
}
#endif
```

Now we use it this way in the caller View:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    /// Is the input dialog displayed
    @State var dialogDisplayed = false
    
    /// The name to edit
    @State var name: String? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(name ?? "Unnamed").frame(width: 200).padding()
            Button(name == nil ? "Set Name" : "Change Name") {
                dialogDisplayed = true
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $dialogDisplayed) {
                Dialog(prompt: name == nil ? "Enter a name" : "Enter a new name", value: $name)
            }
            .onChange(of: name, perform: { value in
                print("Name Changed : \(value)")
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Step1: Make root view as ZStack

Step2: Add variable for show/hide

```
 @State var showAlert = false
```

Step 3:
Add this custom layout inside root view (ZStack)

```
  if $showAlert.wrappedValue {
            ZStack() {
                Color.grayBackground
                VStack {
                    //your custom layout text fields buttons 
                   
                }.padding()
            }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 180,alignment: .center)
            .cornerRadius(20).shadow(radius: 20)
        }
```

Comment: Very clear and precise answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the idea of tanzolone

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class TextFieldAlertViewController: UIViewController {
    
    /// Presents a UIAlertController (alert style) with a UITextField and a `Done` button
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - title: to be used as title of the UIAlertController
    ///   - message: to be used as optional message of the UIAlertController
    ///   - text: binding for the text typed into the UITextField
    ///   - isPresented: binding to be set to false when the alert is dismissed (`Done` button tapped)
    init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, alert: TextFieldAlert) {
        self._isPresented = isPresented
        self.alert = alert
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    @Binding
    private var isPresented: Bool
    private var alert: TextFieldAlert
    
    // MARK: - Private Properties
    private var subscription: AnyCancellable?
    
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        presentAlertController()
    }
    
    private func presentAlertController() {
        guard subscription == nil else { return } // present only once
        
        let vc = UIAlertController(title: alert.title, message: alert.message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        // add a textField and create a subscription to update the `text` binding
        vc.addTextField {
            // TODO: 需要补充这些参数
            // $0.placeholder = alert.placeholder
            // $0.keyboardType = alert.keyboardType
            // $0.text = alert.defaultValue ?? ""
            $0.text = self.alert.defaultText
        }
        if let cancel = alert.cancel {
            vc.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: cancel, style: .cancel) { _ in
                //                self.action(nil)
                self.isPresented = false
            })
        }
        let textField = vc.textFields?.first
        vc.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: alert.accept, style: .default) { _ in
            self.isPresented = false
            self.alert.action(textField?.text)
        })
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

struct TextFieldAlert {
    
    let title: String
    let message: String?
    var defaultText: String = ""
    public var accept: String = "好".localizedString // The left-most button label
    public var cancel: String? = "取消".localizedString // The optional cancel (right-most) button label
    public var action: (String?) -> Void // Triggers when either of the two buttons closes the dialog
    
}

struct AlertWrapper:  UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let alert: TextFieldAlert
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = TextFieldAlertViewController
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AlertWrapper>) -> UIViewControllerType {
        TextFieldAlertViewController(isPresented: $isPresented, alert: alert)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AlertWrapper>) {
        // no update needed
    }
}

struct TextFieldWrapper<PresentingView: View>: View {
    
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let presentingView: PresentingView
    let content: TextFieldAlert
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if (isPresented) {
                AlertWrapper(isPresented: $isPresented, alert: content)
            }
            presentingView
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    
    func alert(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, _ content: TextFieldAlert) -> some View {
        TextFieldWrapper(isPresented: isPresented, presentingView: self, content: content)
    }
    
}
```

How to use

```
        xxxView
        .alert(isPresented: $showForm, TextFieldAlert(title: "添加分组", message: "") { (text) in
            if text != nil {
                self.saveGroup(text: text!)
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

[HostingWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63276688/4728060)+present

```swift
extension UIWindow {
    public func showAlert(alertController: UIAlertController, placeholder: String, primaryTitle: String, cancelTitle: String, primaryAction: @escaping (String) -> Void) {

        alertController.addTextField { textField in
            textField.placeholder = placeholder
        }

        let primaryButton = UIAlertAction(title: primaryTitle, style: .default) { _ in
            guard let text = alertController.textFields?[0].text else { return }
            primaryAction(text)
        }

        let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: cancelTitle, style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        alertController.addAction(primaryButton)
        alertController.addAction(cancelButton)

        self.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a swift package, [swift-ui-accompanist](https://github.com/wycliffw/swift-ui-accompanist) that has a product **AccompanistAlert** that you can add to your project and use as below.

```swift
import AccompanistAlert
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingAddBookUI = false
    @State var newBookName = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: { showingAddBookUI.toggle() }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }
        }
        .accompanist.alert("Add Book", isPresented: $showingAddBookUI) {
            TextField("Book Name", text: $newBookName)

            Button("Save", action: {
                // TODO: Save book to database
                newBookName = ""
            })
            .disabled(newBookName.count < 3)

            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel, action: {
                newBookName = ""
            })
        }
}
```

Notice that the Alert is constructed using the Swift UI DSL you are familiar with and the API is similar to that provided by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Great question I myself have struggled finding a good way of adding a textfield to my Alerts.
And I think I have "solved" it - I found a quite simple way of doing it and I like it, and I hope you will too.

```
struct AlertContent: View {
@State private var showingSimpleAlert = false
@State private var userInput: String = ""
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            self.showingSimpleAlert = true
        }) {
            Text("Simple Alert")
        }
        .alert("Feedback", isPresented: $showingSimpleAlert) {
            TextField("Enter user input", text: $userInput)
            Button("SEND", action: sendUserInput)

        } message: {
            Text("Please give us feedback.")
        }
    }
}

func sendUserInput() {
    print("Sending user input")
}
```

}

And you will get the following result:
[Image of Alert with a text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPnLa.png)

If you want to learn more about alerts in SwiftUI feel free to check out my post here:
https://softwareanders.com/swiftui-alert/

Answer (score -2):

```
func dialog(){

       let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Contry", message: "Write contrt code here", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alertController.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "Country code"
        }

        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { alert -> Void in

            let secondTextField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
            print("county code : ",secondTextField)

        })

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil )


        alertController.addAction(saveAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
```

**Usage**

```
Button(action: { self.dialog()})
 {
Text("Button")
.foregroundColor(.white).fontWeight(.bold)
 }
```