# How to fit popover's size to its content in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the problem that I can't get the popover view of a `Button` to fit the size of its content.

Here's what the problem looks like

[image]

And the Code:

```
Button(action: {
    self.showColorDropDownMenu.toggle()
}, label: {
    Circle()
        .fill(Color.red)
        .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
}).popover(isPresented: self.$showColorDropDownMenu) {
    Text("Hello").background(Color.yellow)
}
```

I tried calling `.frame(...)` with different arguments, but it doesn't seem to work on iPadOS

I saw another question [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58179317/swiftui-sizing-a-popover-to-fit), which talks about the same issue, but I can't comment, yet, so I can't ask if they found a solution and maybe there's another fix to it.

Comment: Does not seem like it’s currently possible to change the frame of a popover.
I created bug report FB7465491, I suggest doing the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed in iOS 13.4, the popover fits to the size of its contents now.