# SwiftUI popover on iPad moves on device rotation

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to get a popover working on an iPad with swiftUI. The popover shows fine, however, when I rotate the device, the popover goes all over the place and does not anchor to its original place. Anybody a solution for this?

```
import SwiftUI

struct PopOver: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello world")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showPopover: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showPopover = true
        }) {
            Text("Select")
        }
        .popover(
            isPresented: self.$showPopover
        ) {
            PopOver()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPad Pro (10.5-inch)"))
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58179317/swiftui-sizing-a-popover-to-fit . Please see answers for this question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: Sizing a popover to fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58179317/swiftui-sizing-a-popover-to-fit)

Comment: I had a look at above suggestions, the problem is not the sizing, the problem is that on rotation the anchor point is not at the correct position anymore. I tried some solutions in above answers without any luck :(

Answer (score 1):

Same as user3441734's answer, just more concise:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var show = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Select") { self.show.toggle() }
            .popover(isPresented: $show, content: {
                PopOver()
            })
            .hideOnRotate(show: $show)
    }
}

extension View {
    func hideOnRotate(show: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification),
                  perform: { _ in show.wrappedValue = false })
    }
}
```

If you want to try to re-show as in the other answer, just add logic in the `perform` block.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround

1. dismiss popover on device rotation
2. show popover again, if it was shown before rotation

   ```
   import SwiftUI


   import SwiftUI
   import UIKit
   import Combine

   struct PopOver: View {
       var body: some View {
           Text("Hello world")
       }
   }

   class Model: ObservableObject {
       @Published var show = false
       var handle: AnyCancellable?
       init() {
           handle = NotificationCenter.Publisher(center: .default, name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification).sink { (_) in
               print("orientation")
               if self.show {
                   self.show = false
                   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                       self.show = true
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       deinit {
           handle?.cancel()
           handle = nil
       }
   }
   struct ContentView: View {
       @ObservedObject var popoverModel = Model()
       var body: some View {
           Button(action: {
               self.popoverModel.show.toggle()
           }) {
               Text("Select")
           }
           .popover(
               isPresented: self.$popoverModel.show
           ) {
               PopOver()
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   WARNING!

   ```
   if self.show {
       self.show = false
       DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
           self.show = true
       }
   }
   ```

is very fragile, you better to find different way how to show popover not before the rotation transition finished.

[image]

Comment: Thanx, indeed a workaround. I'll have a look at this.

Comment: @iTukker fill radar with Apple ... it seems to be a bug :-(, not behavior