# SwiftUI runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage does not work with WKWebView

Tags: swift, swiftui, wkwebview

I'm building a simple webapp with SwiftUI that simply load my website into the webview. From my website, it has to show the Javascript `confirm` for users to able to logout from the app and my function inside of `runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage` crashes the app when Javascript confirm is triggered.

Here is the entire code of my webapp.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct Webview : UIViewRepresentable {
    let request: URLRequest
    var webview: WKWebView?

    init(web: WKWebView?, req: URLRequest) {
        self.webview = WKWebView()
        self.request = req
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKUIDelegate {
        var parent: Webview

        init(_ parent: Webview) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        // Delegate methods go here

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
        runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String,
             initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
             completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

            // alert functionality goes here
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))

            alertController.present(alertController, animated: true)

            completionHandler()

        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
        runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String,
             initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
             completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

            // confirm functionality goes here. THIS CRASHES THE APP
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                completionHandler(true)
            }))

            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                completionHandler(false)
            }))

            alertController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
        runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt prompt: String,
                  defaultText: String?,
             initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
             completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {

            // prompt functionality goes here

        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        return webview!
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.uiDelegate = context.coordinator
        uiView.load(request)
    }

    func goBack(){
        webview?.goBack()
    }

    func goForward(){
        webview?.goForward()
    }

    func reload(){
        webview?.reload()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let webview = Webview(web: nil, req: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!))

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            webview
            HStack() {
                Button(action: {
                    self.webview.goBack()
                }){
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                }.padding(32)

                Button(action: {
                    self.webview.reload()
                }){
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise")
                }.padding(32)

                Button(action: {
                    self.webview.goForward()
                }){
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                }.padding(32)
            }.frame(height: 40)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong in this section for `runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage` that crashes the app.

Here is the part that I'm having a trouble with.

```
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
        runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String,
             initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
             completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

            // confirm functionality goes here. THIS CRASHES THE APP
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                completionHandler(true)
            }))

            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                completionHandler(false)
            }))

            alertController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You have to use SwiftUI `Alert` in this workflow. I would do it via additional wrapper around `Webview` with binding to present alert and, probably additional view model to transfer JS alert parameters.

Comment: @Asperi Thank you for the comment. You meant I need to map Javascript Alert to SwiftUI alert(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/alert) to make this work? Same thing goes for Confirm too then?

Comment: Yes, and these alerts should be presented via SwiftUI `View.alert` function

Answer (score 2):

You need a View Controller to present alert. Try this:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alertController.addAction(
        UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in completionHandler(true) })
    )
    alertController.addAction(
        UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in completionHandler(false) })
    )
    
    if let controller = topMostViewController() {
        controller.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}

private func topMostViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    guard let rootController = keyWindow()?.rootViewController else {
        return nil
    }
    return topMostViewController(for: rootController)
}

private func keyWindow() -> UIWindow? {
    return UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
        .filter {$0.activationState == .foregroundActive}
        .compactMap {$0 as? UIWindowScene}
        .first?.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
}

private func topMostViewController(for controller: UIViewController) -> UIViewController {
    if let presentedController = controller.presentedViewController {
        return topMostViewController(for: presentedController)
    } else if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
        guard let topController = navigationController.topViewController else {
            return navigationController
        }
        return topMostViewController(for: topController)
    } else if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
        guard let topController = tabController.selectedViewController else {
            return tabController
        }
        return topMostViewController(for: topController)
    }
    return controller
}
```

Thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57877120/11212894

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you're trying to present `alertController` from `alertController` and that's a crash reason.