# SwiftUI TextField acts disabled in VStack inside ZStack (simulating an Alert with a TextField)

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I need to make an Alert in **SwiftUI** that has an editable **TextField** in it.  Currently, this isn't supported by SwiftUI (as of **Xcode 11.3**), so I'm looking for a work-around.

I know I can implement by wrapping the normal UIKit bits in a **UIHostingController**, but really want to stick with an all-SwiftUI implementation.

I've got two **VStacks** in a **ZStack**, with the front one (the one with the TextView) being hidden and disabled until until you tap the button.  Take a look at this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isShowingEditField = false
    @State var text: String = "12345"

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Value is \(self.text)")
                Button(action: {
                    print("button")
                    self.isShowingEditField = true
                }) {
                    Text("Tap To Test")
                }
            }
            .disabled(self.isShowingEditField)
            .opacity(self.isShowingEditField ? 0.25 : 1.00)

            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("Edit the text")
                TextField("", text: self.$text)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .lineLimit(1)

                Divider()
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.isShowingEditField = false
                            print("completed... value is \(self.text)")
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("OK")
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.white)
            .shadow(radius: CGFloat(1.0))
            .disabled(!self.isShowingEditField)
            .opacity(self.isShowingEditField ? 1.0 : 0.0)
        }
    }
}
```

This seems like it should work to me.  Switching between the two **VStack**s works well, but the **TextField** is not editable.

It acts like it's disabled, but it's not.  Explicitly **.disabled(false)** to the TextField doesn't help.  Also, it should already be enabled anyway since 1) that's the default, 2) the VStack it's in is specifically being set as enabled, and 3) The OK button works normally.

Ideas/workarounds?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You need to force the TextField updating with some methods. Like the following:

```
    TextField("", text: self.$text)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .lineLimit(1)
                .id(self.isShowingEditField)
```

Comment: wow, it works. do you know, why it don't really works without these force updating methods? It's interesting for me, in what cases you need to add them and why it works as usual if just remove ```.shadow(radius: CGFloat(1.0))``` like I experimented in my answer? Is it a bug?

Comment: Because the `disable` is in the container View, The `TextField ` has to be informed in someway to update the `disable` status. You may find other ways if searching or researching.

Comment: E.Coms -- that doesn't make sense though.  The default is enabled  And you can put .disable(false) on it explicitly, and it makes no difference.  This has got to be a bug though, right?

Comment: You can call anything not intuitive a bug. But if we want to fix it, we have to figure out why the implementation not working as expected.

Answer (score 6):

That is really ridiculous, but the problem disappears if you comment just one line of code:

```swift
//.shadow(radius: CGFloat(1.0))
```

I commented it and everything works. I think you need to use `ZStack` somewhere in your custom alert view to avoid this.. hm, bug, maybe?

**update**
try some experiments. If you leave just this code in that View:

```swift
struct CustomAlertWithTextField: View {

    @State var isShowingEditField = false
    @State var text: String = "12345"

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $text)
            .padding()
            .shadow(radius: CGFloat(1.0))
    }
}
```

it would not work again. only if you comment `.padding()` or `.shadow(...)`

**BUT** if you relaunch Xcode - this code begin to work (which made me crazy). Tried it at Xcode Version 11.2 (11B52)

**update 2** the working code version:

```swift
struct CustomAlertWithTextField: View {

    @State var isShowingEditField = false
    @State var text: String = "12345"

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Value is \(self.text)")
                Button(action: {
                    print("button")
                    self.isShowingEditField = true
                }) {
                    Text("Tap To Test")
                }
            }
            .disabled(self.isShowingEditField)
            .opacity(self.isShowingEditField ? 0.25 : 1.00)

            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.white)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
                    .shadow(radius: 1) // moved shadow here, so it doesn't affect TextField now

                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text("Edit the text")
                    TextField("", text: self.$text)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .frame(width: 298)

                    Divider().frame(width: 300)

                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.isShowingEditField = false
                                print("completed... value is \(self.text)")
                            }
                        }) {
                            Text("OK")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.white)
            .disabled(!self.isShowingEditField)
            .opacity(self.isShowingEditField ? 1.0 : 0.0)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: wow thanks for fiddling with it that much.  I'll try out your updates.  Clearly there is some bugginess going on here on Apple's side.  Don't you think?

Comment: @drewster yeah, I think that is some kind of bug

Answer (score 2):

after some research i solved this problem by adding `.clipped()` to the VStack.

For your problem, it would look like this:

```
VStack(alignment: .center) {
    Text("Edit the text")
    TextField("", text: self.$text)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .lineLimit(1)

    Divider()
    HStack {
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
                self.isShowingEditField = false
                print("completed... value is \(self.text)")
            }
        }) {
            Text("OK")
        }
    }
}
.padding()
.clipped() // <- here
.background(Color.white)
.shadow(radius: CGFloat(1.0))
.disabled(!self.isShowingEditField)
.opacity(self.isShowingEditField ? 1.0 : 0.0)
```